# Plot normal probability for effect estimates in factorial design in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, categorical-data, treatment-effect

I have 2 level  Design (DOE) with 4 factors (A,B,C,D). I've already calculated the estimates for each main effect and all the interaction effects.

How can I construct the normal probability plot to see which effects are significant? I have looked at many packages in R for Design of Experiment but cannot find a package that produces the plot.

How can I construct the plot with all the estimates I have by code in R

Thank you.

Comment: Typically, significance is assessed with p-values and normal probability plots are used only to help interpret those p-values (by assessing whether the distributional assumptions needed to compute them are plausibly consistent with the data). I am therefore curious how you would use the normal probability plot directly to "see which effects are significant."  How exactly would that work?

Answer (score 5):

In R you can just pass the vector of effects to the `qqnorm` function.  If you want the points labeled then save the result of `qqnorm` and use that with the `text` or `identify` functions.

```
mydata <- expand.grid( A=c(-1,1), B=c(-1,1), C=c(-1,1), D=c(-1,1) )
mydata$y <- rnorm( nrow(mydata) )

fit <- lm( y ~ .^4, data=mydata )

tmp <- qqnorm( coef(fit) )
qqline( coef(fit) )
text( tmp$x, tmp$y, names(coef(fit)), pos=3 )
# or
identify( tmp$x, tmp$y, names(coef(fit)))
```

Comment: Until you posted this I was under the misimpression that the *residuals* should be plotted, but yours seems to be the correct interpretation of what was asked.  Since you seem to have understood the question, could you enlighten me concerning the follow-up comment I have posted to it?  I was wondering how this output could be used to "see which effects are significant." It seems to me it cannot be so used directly (am I overlooking something?), but possibly it could if it were accompanied with additional graphical elements related (say) to an HSD test or something similar.

Comment: @whuber, in a screening design (full factorial or fractional factorial) with no replication (each combination of conditions is only tested once) the traditional p-values cannot be calculated since you would have 0 degrees of freedom for estimating variance.  Under the null hypothesis that all effects (main and interactions) are 0 the estimated effect sizes will be linear combinations of normal errors (assumption on the normality) and therefore be random normals themselves.  So effects on the qqnorm plot that deviate from normality are suggestive of significant effects.

Comment: Thank you!  (Without justification I had implicitly assumed replication must have occurred in one or more cells.)

Comment: I wanted to comment because I found this quite handy, but needed to manipulate your code a bit to get a factor effects plot more like something like DesignExpert would output. Mostly, you might recommend deleting the intercept with coef(fit)[-1]; in data that haven't been standardized, with a non-zero overall mean, it tends to skew the effects plot badly if the effects are small relative to the intercept.

Comment: @plagueheart, thanks, that is an important point.  In my example it did not matter since the overall mean is 0, but for real data situations the mean would be different from 0 and could throw things off.  Your comment is an important addition.

Answer (score 1):

First order the data (effects and interactions), then calculate the probability of each data with this formula: $P=i/(n+1)$ where $n$ is the total data (16 in your case) and $i$ the order (1, 2, 3 and so on). After that calculate the inverse probability function (I think is called a z-score). I think the Excel function to do this is `NORMINV` with the probability as an argument (inverse probability: `NORMINV(P)`). Finally graph the data versus the inverse probability (i.e., z-score). Where the data is on the X axis and the z-score is on the Y axis.